# Q JavaFX changed ObservVal not trigger event when using shift+HOME

Tags: javafx

I have a simple textbox in JavaFX called txtBxFilterTOPNL18. 
Everytime the user types a letter my code is triggered. 
But if the box already has text in it and the user marks the text in the box by using SHIFT-HOME and then presses "Backspace" or "Delete", the event is not triggered. 
 
In other words, if the user empties the textbox, the code does not detect it. 

 Am I missing anything here?

```
txtBxFilterTOPNL18.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if(txtBxFilterTOPNL18.textProperty().get().isEmpty())
            {
                return;
            }
            ObservableList<ObservableList> TOPNL18tabledataMirror=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ObservableList<TableColumn<ObservableList, ?>> cols=TOPNL18table.getColumns();
               //do something here....
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As strange as it seems, I restarted NetBeans and now it works! :\